# Virtual keyboard for QtWebKit based browser or how can I get the currently focused text field?

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit, virtual-keyboard

I'm working on implementing a virtual keyboard for a QtWebKit based browser. I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding how QtWebKit paints the controls within the actual page. Initially I thought they were QLineEdit instances, but they are not. Diving into implementation it appears that the glue code between Qt and WebKit paints the text field using QStyle and QPainter. Unfortunately, I'm very new to Qt and so I dont understand where in the event loop the mouse presses for these events are interpreted. I found Editor::canEdit() deep in the call stack, and now I can bring up the virtual keyboard when the user clicks on a text field within the page. The virtual keyboard then expected a pointer to a QWidget instance, but Edito::canEdit() doesn't carry that information and I can't find anywhere where a QWidget like instance is exposed. I'm really stumped, any advice would be most welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get better luck by hooking the virtual keyboard into the Qt input method system. Search for "InputMethod" in the source code of QtWebKit Api, i.e. the qweb*.* files.

Comment: As of Qt 4.5.2 you can't hook in into WebKit's input mechanisms, but they've added supporting structure to 4.6.